# camera's move is so lined inside camera tour

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

h1, archilogic guys! It this possible? I don't like lined moves of camera inside tour. 
On archilogic site only 'floor plan view' available for 'presentation'. i made tour with camera rotation, and he is beautiful except lined moves of camera. W8ing for the curve motion path. By the way, your  is looks like deprecated SMILL, netherly?
p.s. i'm first time in aframe and three, only SVG before
p.p.s. svg keyframes doesn't work inside aframe texture, over...
[image]

p.p.p.s. ok, SMILL fail too...

Comment: we don't offer custom motion curves
this is where the magic happens
https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/blob/master/src/aframe/component/tour.js#L111
you could implement your own animation logic if you want to

Comment: ofc i want! But my skillz is so low now. I came in web from Blender, and i will push dat forward, true!